# What words can express the act of sharing in a collective sense, as opposed to a distributive sense

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, synonyms

I would like words or very concise statements that express the act of working together and sharing items/resources to a **common location** for the benefit of a group of people that the items are being shared with.

To give you some background, I am struggling to think of a name for my web application which is built to allow groups of users (friends, colleagues etc.) to share digital resources to a central location. As a starting point, I tried to find alternative words for "sharing" but the only suggestions I could find were more suited to describing the allocation/division of resources. I would like words which describe sharing between people to a common location.

Comment: Can you give more context? What type of items, what circumstances, what kind of group?

Answer (score 5):

**Pool** could fit. As a verb, it can be used to mean combining the resources of several people or organizations so they can be used collectively.

Definition from the free dictionary:

**Pool**
v. pooled, pool·ing, pools
v.tr.
To put into a pool, as for common use: Let's pool our resources to finish the project quickly.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pool

Comment: Synonym: "mutualization" (of resources).

Answer (score 1):

**Communal** - Shared or used by members of a group or community

Communal works great as an adjective to describe a shared location or resource between a group of people.  Commonly used in phrases like 'communal land' or 'communal kitchen'

In the context of a location for sharing digitally, you could use something along the lines of 'communal repository', 'communal drop', or 'communal cache'.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/communal